# Line on animated matplotlib graph not showing up

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, plot, widget

I'm not sure why a graph line isn't showing on my widget.

The x-axis is moving with time as it should, and when I print the y-values that should be plotted (Temp), new values come up as expected. However, no line/points show up on the plot.

I've had a similar issue with a plot in the past, which was solved by changing the style of the points plotted (i.e. using 'r*' to make the points visible red stars). I'm not sure how to implement the same sort of thing in this code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import datetime
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    Time = []
    Temp = []
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    y = numpy.random.randint(48,52)
    Time.append(x)
    Temp.append(int(y))    

    ax1.plot(Time,Temp)
    print(Temp)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put Time and Temp out of function animate

```
Time = []
Temp = []
def animate(i):
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    y = numpy.random.randint(48,52)
    Time.append(x)
    Temp.append(int(y))    
    ax1.plot(Time,Temp)
    print(Temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `marker` and it shows the points:

```
ax1.plot(Time,Temp, marker="s")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, super helpful!